# What is the value of the angle $x$ of the given triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

I have found $\angle BDE+x=130^\circ$. But I can solve from this. How can I find $x$?

Comment: Inspect each triangle and write down all the angle measures.

Comment: @AndrewChin, maybe I'm wrong, but I don't want to confuse the OP. $\measuredangle=40^{\circ}$ and $\measuredangle BCA=20^{\circ}$, but this isn't a right-angle triangle... and $\Delta ABD$ isn't isosceles.... so it is useless, isn't it?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3620825/langleys-adventitious-angles/3621250#3621250

Answer (score 1):

Try expressing all angles in terms of $x$. You should get the following:

[image]

Now use [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) to get the following relations:

From Triangle $ABE$,
$$\
\frac{BE}{\sin(70)} = \frac{AB}{\sin(30)} \quad \text{ and } \quad \frac{BE}{\sin(70)} = \frac{AE}{\sin(80)}
$$
From Triangle $ADB$,
$$\
\frac{AD}{\sin(60)} = \frac{AB}{\sin(40)}
$$
From Triangle $ADE$,
$$\
\frac{AD}{\sin(x)} = \frac{AE}{\sin(170-x)}
$$
Solving the above equations we get,
$$\
\frac{\sin(60)}{\sin(40)\sin(x)} = \frac{\sin(80)}{\sin(30)\sin(170-x)}
$$
Finally,
$$\
\implies x=20 \deg
$$
**Note**: All angles are in degree.
**Link**: [Wolframalpha Solution to Trignomteric Equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20sin%2860Degree%29%2F%28sin%2840Degree%29sin%28x%29%29%20%3D%20%20sin%2880Degree%29%2F%28sin%2830Degree%29sin%28170Degree-x%29%29)