# Find measure of required angle in isosceles triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Triangle ABC is isosceles triangle with AB = AC. And angle A = 20°. Point D is on side AC such that angle CBD = 70°. Similarly, point E is on side AB such that angle BCE = 60°. Now, points D and E are joined. Then find measure of angle BDE.
I found other angles. I tried using sine rule. But, its getting harder by applying sine rule. I don't know whether I am missing some important theorem. 
Please help. 
I'm sorry that I'm unable to provide diagram.

Comment: Please indicate how you could or not proceed.

Comment: Posted here several times. I'll try to find one. Ah – https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3620825/langleys-adventitious-angles

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you so much I understood the solution.