# Angle of triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle such that $\angle ABC=20^\circ$, $AB=BC$. Let $D \in AB$, $E \in BC$, $AD=BE=AC$. Find angle $\angle BDE$. Does this problem have a nice geometric solution?

I don't like my trigonometric solution. Let $AC=b$, $AB=a$, $\angle BDE=x$. From triangle $BDE$ we have: $$\frac{b}{\sin x}=\frac{a-b}{\sin\left(20^\circ+x\right)}$$
Then $\sin20^\circ \cot x+\cos20^\circ=\frac{a}{b}-1$.
But $$\frac{a}{b}-1=\frac{\sin80^\circ }{\sin20^\circ}-1=2\cos20^\circ $$

Then $\cot x =\cot 20^\circ $. Then $\angle BDE=20^\circ$.
[image]

Comment: This looks like a variation of Langley's Adventitious Angles.

Comment: Does this help you? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3621501

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/index.html

Comment: Intelligenti pauca, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative path with Euclidean geometry. Let $F$ be the point in $\triangle ABC$ such that $\triangle ACF$ is equilateral.

1. Show that $\triangle BDE \cong \triangle CEF$ (SAS criterion).
2. Noting that $ABEF$ is an isosceles trapezoid, and therefore $EF\parallel AB$, conclude that $\measuredangle FEC = 20^\circ$.
3. Obtain the thesis from the fact that $\triangle CEF$ is isosceles and point 1., which yields $ED \cong EB$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

The given figure can be treated as a part of a "bigger figure" i.e., as part of a star-shaped 9-gon:

[image]

*Fig. 1.*

making it accessible to a rather natural proof also based on angle chasing but seemingly in a more logical way.

Two steps:

**Step 1:** Why is the red triangle in fig. 1 identical to the initial figure ?

- $a:=\angle{B}=20°$ because the associated center angle is $2a = 40°=\frac19 360°$,
- $BE=AD$ (all the "spikes" of the star are identical),
- $AC=AD$ because triangle $ACF$ is equilateral. Indeed $\angle{CAF}=\angle{CAF}=60°$ because they both sustain 3 times arc $a$.

**Step 2:** Now, let us prove that $\angle{BDE} = 20°$. It  follows from the fact that lines $DE$ and $AF$ are parallel, as a consequence of the symmetry of the figure with respect to the axis of symmetry $OG$ where $O$ is the center of the circle.

Remark: The nine-pointed star is an ["enneagram (9/4)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enneagram_(geometry)) if you want to explain at a dinner what you are doing.

Comment: btw, had the vertex angle been $30^{\circ}$ would  we get a hexagon star?

Comment: @Narasimham Alas, dealing with the hexagon, you cannot generate a star in this way: the "star of David" is in fact done in two parts (constituted of two triangles). Number $7$ is better behaved...

Comment: Thanks for this clarification..

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: nice geometrical approach and explanation !

Comment: @G Cab  Thanks. This kind of approach should probably be valuable for other problems of this type (some integer angles in degrees + some equalities between lengths).

Answer (score 2):

[image: Triangle ABC]

Reflect $\triangle ABC$ over line $CA$. Let the reflections of points $D$ and $E$ be $D'$ and $E'$ respectively. Draw $DD'$ and $BD'$.

Observe that $\triangle DCD'$ is equilateral and thereafter quadrilateral $D'DBC$ is a kite.

Hence, $\angle ABD'=\frac {1}{2} \angle DBC=40^{\circ}$. Thus $\triangle ABD'$ is isosceles and thereafter $BD'=AD'$. Also, $AD'=AD=AB-BD=AC-AE=CE$ and hence $BD'=CE$.

Now, observe that, in $\triangle ED'C$ and $\triangle BDD'$, $D'C=DD'$, $CE=BD'$ an $\angle ECD=30^{\circ}=\angle BD'D$ and therefore $\triangle ED'C\cong \triangle BDD'$ by $S-A-S$ criterion of congruence and hence $BD=ED'$.

Also, since $ED'=DE$ and $BD=AE$, $AE=DE$ and therefore $\angle BDE=\angle DAE=20^{\circ}$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Witold Welcome .