# Geometry Question on angle chasing

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

[image: Question figure]

In $\Delta ABC$, $\angle EAF=10^{\circ}$, $\angle FAB=70^{\circ}$, $\angle FBA=60^{\circ}$, $\angle DBF=20^{\circ}$. The goal is to find $\angle EDA$.

I have tried this question for some time and am unable to find the required angle. On manually measuring angles, I found that $\angle EDA = 20^{\circ}$, which implies that $\Delta CDE\sim \Delta BFD$. I have tried to prove this result using sine rule but got nowhere. Also, I have checked and there are no cyclic quadrilaterals in this configuration. So, there might be a clever construction that solves this problem. Any solution will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot. Please try not to use values of $\cos 20$ and such in your solution as this may not be provided in contest math.

Comment: Take a look at the recent solution I have given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4148450/angle-of-triangle/4148712#4148712) by embedding this triangle into a stellated polygon.

Comment: @Jean Marie, the question has differing constraints as compared to mine. The question in the link provides the condition, $CD=AE=AB$(According to my figure), but this is not necessary according to the constraints in my question(given only angles). Please clarify

Comment: @MatthewDaly, this question requires the knowledge of cosines of angles like $20^{\circ}$ and this is contest math, where the values may not be provided

Comment: Here is a page dedicated to this problem and all its variants: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/index.shtml